# awk: delete the lines with the same first field after a match

Tags: awk

(Updated example and solution) The data is grouped sequentially by the first fields.  The numbers of lines with each first field are variable.   After a match (of unfavored keywords) is found, the lines with the same first field as the match need be deleted.

Input is:

```
1  orange  dog    red
1  apple   cat    green
2  peach   frog   grey
3  apple  lamb   white
3  orange  lamb   white
3  mango   cat    yellow
3  apple   mouse  blue
```

If a match of either "cat" or "orange", the lines with the same first fields ("1" or "3") are deleted.  The output will be:

```
2  peach   frog   grey
```

The solution is from Costas:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{if($0~/cat|orange/)L[$1]=1;next} !($1 in L)' test1.txt test1.txt
```

Comment: This looks like a homework question. What have you tried so far? Does it have to be an awk solution? Looks like you'll need to 'two-pass' the data, because you won't know if a match occurs until you've read all records.

Comment: `"3  apple   mouse  blue"` why not ? .... because 3 in first column

Comment: I think because `3 mango cat yellow` contains a disallowed keyword.

Comment: Awk is the only language I know (barely) and I try to finish my project with awk only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sh
awk '
# pass input 1 time to find all occurence of "cat"
NR==FNR{
    if( $0~/cat/)
        L[$1]=1 # add founded 1st field into array L
    next
       }
# for second pass print line if value of 1st field is not in array L
!($1 in L)' input input
```

Comment: Since I have very limited experience with awk, I really appreciate it if you could provide the full command lines I can test with.

Comment: based on your script, I tried the following command, but always get error message.    `awk 'NR==FNR{if($0~/(cat|orange)/){L[$1]=1;next} !($1 in L) {print $0}' test1.txt test1.txt`   The error message is `awk: syntax error at source line 1
 context is
 NR==FNR{if($0~/(cat|orange)/){L[$1]=1;next} !($1 in L) >>>  { <<< 
awk: illegal statement at source line 1
awk: illegal statement at source line 1
 missing }`

Comment: @DonXu you have to remove extra `{` in `orange)/){L[$1]` The correct line is `NR==FNR{if($0~/cat|orange/)L[$1]=1;next} !($1 in L)' test1.txt test1.txt`

Answer (score 1):

if the line does a match with the terms and also the first column isn't included in the dictionary `f` then printing

```
awk '{
  if($0!~/(cat|orange)/){ 
    if(!($1 in f)){
      print $0;
    }
  }else{ 
    f[$1]=1
  }
}' input
```

Comment: @AlexA. I am awaiting a response from OP ..... because if it doesn't work I could delete .....

Comment: I tried it again, it worked!  (I miss-typed something) Thanks a lot!

Comment: My original example was not the best.  Because, if the unfavored keywords are not in the first row:  (see Example #2 above), the lines before the first unfavored keywords will be missed.  Jose, your script will return " 2  peach   frog   grey 3  apple  lamb   white" on Example #2.

Comment: @DonXu then, Costas´s solution is better

Answer (score 0):

If a non-awk answer is OK, in perl I'd do it like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @disallowed_keywords = qw ( cat orange );

my %records;
my %ids_to_reject;

my $reject_regex = join( "|", @disallowed_keywords );
$reject_regex = qr/$reject_regex/;

while ( my $line = <DATA> ) {
    my ($id) = split( ' ', $line );
    push( @{ $records{$id} }, $line );
    if ( $line =~ $reject_regex ) { $ids_to_reject{$id}++ }
}

foreach my $id ( sort keys %records ) {
    if ( not $ids_to_reject{$id} ) {
        print join( "\n", @{ $records{$id} } ), "\n";
    }
}

__DATA__ 
1  orange  dog    red
1  apple   cat    green
2  peach   frog   grey
3  orange  lamb   white
3  mango   cat    yellow
3  apple   mouse  blue
```

Comment: Thanks for your input.  But awk is the only thing I know (barely).

Comment: I won't dispute choices, but I'll point out - `awk` is very powerful, but good for particular tasks - and whilst perl has a reputation for being difficult to read, `awk` can be worse!